# bigquery - current_date() inconsistent result?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I ran current_date() in datalab notebook today(2017 April 12 in UTC), found inconsistent results from two dialects by chance. Why is it?

Actually I am using standard dialect and wanted to get the exact current day in UTC which should be 2017-04-12, how should I accomplish it then?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There was a [bug recently reported](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1195) and fixed ([8498fa6](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/commit/8498fa6c0f631c08b3e9a5b0801d874ed3d98ce9)) in the [Google Cloud Datalab GitHub repository](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab) .

It's possible that this issue has already been resolved in the latest Datalab release. Could you try upgrading Google Cloud Datalab?

The date/times appear correct (in UTC) in the latest Datalab version.

If the issue still exists, it would also be interesting to see the results of

```
%%sql
SELECT CURRENT_TIME()
```

and

```
%%sql -d standard
SELECT CURRENT_TIME()
```

or, the results of the equivalent magic command from the new `google.datalab` library:

```
%bq query
SELECT CURRENT_TIME()
```

Note: The legacy SQL dialect is no longer supported in Google Cloud Datalab according to the `datalab` to `google.datalab` [Migration Guide](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/wiki/%60datalab%60-to-%60google.datalab%60-Migration-Guide) which is linked to from the [Release notes](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/releases).